# How to get last months total web page views with Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this post_views table

```
created_at         post_id       ip
==========         =======       =======
01-01-2020            3            127.0.0.1
01-01 2020            5            127.0.0.1
02-01 2020            5            127.0.0.1
03-01 2020            5            222.33.44.55

06-02 2020            3            222.33.44.55
06-02 2020            3            127.0.0.1
10-02 2020            5            33.44.55.66

02-03 2020            3            22.33.65.22
02-03 2020            3            22.33.65.22
02-03 2020            5            11.44.55.66
```

I need to sum every day visits to get 3 last months total web Page views using this table ,I mean this results:

```
January= 3 visits
February = 3 visits
March = 2 visits
```

Comment: You can use `whereMonth` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope something like this will help you.

Inside your `Post` model:

```
public function getLastThreeMonthViewsByIP($ip)
{
    $data = [];

    // loop 3 months
    for ($i = -3; $i < 0; $i++)
    {
        $timestamp = strtotime("$i month");
        
        $monthNumber = date('n', $timestamp);

        // from this post
        $result = $this->views()
            // in this month
            ->whereMonth('created_at', $monthNumber)
            // from this ip
            ->where('ip', $ip)
            // group IP
            ->groupBy('ip')
            // count all
            ->selectRaw('count(*) AS total')
            // and return first 
            ->first();

        // if there are any results, add to data
        if ($result)
        {
            $monthName = date('F', $timestamp);

            $data[] = [
                'monthNumber' => $monthNumber,
                'monthName' => $monthName,
                'total' => $result->total,
            ];
        }
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: thank you, it was very helpfull, but I need to count just one view per day unless is another ip .

Comment: Can you explain it a little more?

Comment: Oh, I see, the ```post_id``` does not matter. You need the app/project total unique (ip) views per month. Am I right?

Comment: I need to get views count for a column chart about the 3 last months web page visits from post_views table ... so we consider just 1 view per day for each ip and sum that views each month as total

Comment: yes you are right :), every ip can make 1 view every day

Comment: Since you clear my thoughts up, I did make some tests with the data you provided above. The results I posted in a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate this information running the next SQL query:

```
SELECT month, count(*) AS total
FROM (
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') AS month
    FROM post_views
    GROUP BY month, ip
) AS calculated
GROUP BY month;
```

Result:

```
2020-01, 3
2020-02, 3
2020-03, 2
```

To make it work with Laravel:

```
$result = DB::raw("
    SELECT month, count(*) AS total
    FROM (
        SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') AS month
        FROM `post_views`
        WHERE `created_at` >= DATE_FORMAT(now() - interval ? month, '%Y-%m-01') 
        GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`created_at`, '%Y-%m'), ip
    ) AS calculated
    GROUP BY `month`
", [3]); // last 3 months

dd($result); // to see results
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: I got an error in laravel 5.8... the first answer gave me an idea to get total views but using session ids

Comment: When I test it it shows the same ;  Expression {#542 ▼
  #value: """
    
        SELECT month, count(*) AS total
        FROM (
            SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m') AS month
            FROM `post_views`...................